# Calculating city density in GIS

Tags: density

There's a city called http://map.vmr.gov.ua/ in which each house has a type (for living, offices etc) and number of floors.

I want to find out city density - i.e. to assign certain amount of people to each house, avaliable for living (using average family statistics and typical amount of families for each floor) to find out general density, make a sort of heat map and to find out most and least dense parts of city.

I'm mostly new to GIS systems.

Answer (score 1):

You will want to have data, such as building locations, types, and census data. Census information (dwelling and number of people per dwelling, etc.) will need to be in the attributes if the buildings. When you have all this information you will want to run spatial analysis, such as IDW, which will give you a heat map effect.

Answer (score 0):

we have developed a script that helps us calculate the density of our county. We use property appraiser data and the Census data to do a calculation of density by census block:

```
Number of residential units X average household size = density
```